# iOS in-app purchase used for post promotion

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm building an iOS app where the user can post new content and they can also choose to 'promote' that content via an in-app purchase.

Looking around I can't find any details on whether this is allowed or how exactly it would be handled.

The user could in theory promote N number of posts, so a one-off purchase isn't enough, it could N x $0.99 or whatever.

What would be the best way of implementing such a system - and also have each purchase tied to it's originating item (the posting)?

Comment: I think we'd need more context here.  On the one hand paying to promote your posts (I assume contribution to some kind of system with UGC) is astro-turfing, whereas on the other it's just paid advertising.   Am I missing something in the middle ground that is more benign?

Comment: I guess when it comes down to it, it would be considered paid advertising. It would allow those posts to appear as 'featured'. I couldn't find anything disallowing this, but I may have missed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found this could work by setting up the IAP as a 'consumable'. Just in case anyone else ever needs something similar!